# MediaWiki How do I get the [Collapse] link to NOT move position with the text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

When you click on `[Expand]` the `[Collapse]` link appears but shifts over to the right along with the length of the text.
I don't want the `[Collapse]` link to move to the right, I want it to say put.

How do I get the `[Collapse]` link to NOT move position with the text?

```
{| class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed" style="text-align:left;"<br>
! '''Header'''<br>
|-<br>
|<br>
Line1: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
Line2: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
Line3: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
Line4: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
Line5: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
|}
```

Answer (score 1):

To stop the expand / collapse link from moving, you can set a width on the table, e.g.:

```
{| class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed"
! style="width: 50em" | '''Header'''
|-
| Line1: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
  Line2: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
  Line3: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
  Line4: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
  Line5: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
|}
```

(I removed the extra `<br>` elements and the align: left)

Unfortunately, the table header will still shift position slightly due to the difference in width between "Expand" and "Collapse". If you want to stop that movement, you can add a statement to Mediawiki:Common.css, the global stylesheet for the wiki, to specify the width for the toggle. Checking the source, the toggle is in an element of class `.mw-collapsible-toggle`, so you can specify the width in Mediawiki:Common.css with a statement like this:

```
.mw-collapsible-toggle { width: 5em; }
```

You can also align the header left (as you had in your original example) instead of centrally.

Comment: I copy/pasted your example but it doesn't work. The [Collapse] link still shifts the length of the text. I also implemented your CSS and also aligned the header left as I had. It still shifts.

Comment: It probably shifts because the leading spaces makes the content wrapped in a `<pre>`-tag, that forces the table to became wider. The solution is correct, you just have to implement it for your content.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "you just have to implement it for your content". Can you give me an example. If you remove the leading pipe (|) and all of the leading spaces, the text gets displayed, then the [Expand]/[Collapse] link with the behaviour I want, the [Expand]/[Collapse] doesn't shift. Of course it doesn't display the text either, but at least it demonstrates what I want the [Expand]/[Collapse] to behave (no shifting).

Comment: "You just have to implement it for your content" means that instead of pasting in _A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>_, you use real text from your wiki. You can also experiment with using different widths--I chose 50em because it looked like approximately the length of your lines of text. You may want to alter that figure and to set a max-width on the table cells, as leo suggests in his solution.

Comment: Sorry I'm having such a difficult time understanding, but what does "real text from your wiki" mean?

Comment: Use text from your wiki, not example text.

Answer (score 0):

girlwithglasses' solutiuon is correct. However, if the [collapse] link still moves around, it's because the content (that is put between `<pre>`-tags due to the spacing) forces the table to be more than 50em wide. You could prevent that by explicitly setting the max-width of the cell:

```
{| class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed"
! style="width: 50em" | '''Header'''
|-
| style="max-width: 50em" |
  Line1: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
  Line2: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
  Line3: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
  Line4: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
  Line5: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
|}
```

...or, of course, by removing the leading spaces:

```
{| class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed"
! style="width: 50em" | '''Header'''
|-
| Line1: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
Line2: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
Line3: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
Line4: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
Line5: A long line of text that is used to test the position of the [Collapse] link in my document.<br>
|}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of setting max-width of the cell so that the [Exapand]/[Collapse] links don't shift.

Comment: See the [Mediawiki guide to table formatting](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Table) for information on how to set the maximum width of a table cell.

Comment: I searched "Mediawiki guide to table formatting" for the words max, max-width, and width. It showed examples of row width and column width, but no max-width. And won't max-width still make the [Collapse] link shift to the width of whatever you set?

Comment: This line:

`| style="width: 50em" | '''Header'''`

allows you to add css styling to your table. You can put any valid css statements into `| style="..." |`. `width` and `max-width` are both css attributes; if you don't know how to use them, you should be able to find plenty of css guides via google.